# Why getExternalFilesDirs() doesn't work on some devices?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

My app runs on Android 5.0. I use method `getExternalFilesDirs()` to check if external SD card is available. If it returns more than 1 `File`, that means external SD card exists.

But on some devices (for example Elephone G2), method `getExternalFilesDirs()` returns only one directory of primary storage. I'm sure that device has external SD card (/storage/sdcard1/).

Can any one give me the answer?

Comment: Presumably, the manufacturer of the Elephone decided not to allow developers to have access to removable media. Or, perhaps they screwed up when configuring their ROM.

Comment: @CommonsWare It should be the answer. I really don't understand why `getExternalFilesDirs()` doesn't work. It works on almost devices.

Comment: Do you have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @Shark Of course yes. As I said, it works on almost devices.

Comment: @Sunshinetpu looks like you stumled on a half-assed vendor ROM :/

Comment: Yes that happens on many kitkat devices. Try `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");` and `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");`.

Comment: @greenapps It even happens on some Lollipop devices.

Comment: @greenapps I tried with `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` and it returned */storage/emulated/legacy*. What is it? In my device I have */storage/sdcard1*. They are different folders.

Comment: I wait to comment until you tried the one with secondary storage too. For the rest it looks as if you never browsed with a file explorer app on your device because then you would know these paths.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For getExternalFilesDirs to return the path of the sdcard, the OEM must have set the `SECONDARY_STORAGE` environment variable in the device specific init.rc file as mentioned here: 
https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example.html

Look at the source of `getExternalFilesDirs` here:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1039

The value is obtained from `Environment.buildExternalStorageAppFilesDirs`. Look at that source here:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#206

The value is dependent on `mExternalDirsForApp`, which in turn is populated by reading the contents of SECONDARY_STORAGE variable:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#136

As you can see, if the SECONDARY_STORAGE variable is not set, the sdcard path will not be returned.
You can cross-check this by going to `adb shell` and looking at the output of `echo $SECONDARY_STORAGE`

Comment: Thank you. So if the SECONDARY_STORAGE variable is not set, we cannot access the external sd card?

Comment: If that environment variable is not set, you can't write to the sdcard by making use of getExternalFilesDirs since its not going to return the sdcard path. You can however ask the user permissions to write to sdcard through SAF. Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop/26765884#26765884

Comment: Actually, if the device doesn't support `$SECONDARY_STORAGE`, all you need to do is ask for **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission.  No other modification is needed, and I tested this.

Answer (score 8):

In my projects using this code & i don't have any problem.

method of getExternalFilesDirs return array with 2 length.

`Dirs[0] ==> Internal Sorage
 Dirs[1] ==> External Storage`

```
 File[] Dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MyApp.GetContext(), null);
```

Comment: Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? Can you create files using your method?

Comment: The OP specifically ask for a method not working...that you are using in your answer...

Comment: @MHossein I will test your code. Could you please explain why you use `ContextCompat`? I use method `getExternalFilesDirs(String fileName)` of `Context`.  It works on almost devices.

Comment: It shoul dbe noted that, MHossein is using `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs`   not `Context. getExternalFilesDirs`.  [Src link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#219)

Comment: @MHossein Why does the filePath has to contain "sdcard"?

Comment: @Sunshinetpu for my device(huawei) Context returns internal storage.

Comment: @MHossein ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MyApp.GetContext(), null) still returns only one directory of internal storage.

Comment: do you add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

Comment: `getExternalFilesDirs` shouldn't need **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission.  Only `getExternalStorageDirectory` needs this permission.

Comment: It works at 5.0 android tv (XiaoMi tv box 3C) but doesn't work at 4.4.4 (XiaoMi gen 1)

Answer (score 2):

this issue there is in some of Lenovo device too.

my solution is this.

```
String EXTERNAL_SD_PATH1;
String EXTERNAL_SD_PATH2;

public boolean hasExternalSDCard()
{
    try
    {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
        return true;
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {}

    return false;
}

        @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
        protected synchronized void _prepareStorage()
        {
            EXTERNAL_SD_PATH1 = null;
            EXTERNAL_SD_PATH2 = null;
            if (hasExternalSDCard())
            {
                try
                {
                    if(VERSION_SDK_INT > 18)
                    {
                        Context context = getContext();
                        File[]  sds = getExternalFilesDirs("");

                        if(sds == null)
                            return;

                        if(sds.length >= 2)
                        {
                            EXTERNAL_SD_PATH1 = TextWorker.getSubStringBeforeLastMark(sds[1].getAbsolutePath(),"/Android/");
                            if(sds.length > 2)
                                EXTERNAL_SD_PATH2 = TextWorker.getSubStringBeforeLastMark(sds[2].getAbsolutePath(),"/Android/");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String internal = sds[0].getAbsolutePath();
                            internal = TextWorker.getSubStringBeforeLastMark(internal,"/Android/");
                            int len = internal.length();
                            int num = Integer.valueOf(internal.substring(len - 1));

                            String ex1 = internal.substring(0, len-1) + (num+1);
                            File sd1 = new File(ex1);
                            if(sd1.exists())
                                EXTERNAL_SD_PATH1 = sd1.getAbsolutePath();

                            String ex2 = internal.substring(0, len-1) + (num+2);
                            File sd2 = new File(ex2);
                            if(sd2.exists())
                                EXTERNAL_SD_PATH2 = sd2.getAbsolutePath();
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        String path = sd.getAbsolutePath();
                        if (sd.exists() && (path.contains("/mnt/") || path.contains("/storage") || path.contains("/sdcard")) && (!path.contains("emulate")))
                        {
                            EXTERNAL_SD_PATH1 = path;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable e)
                {}
            }

        }


        public static String getSubStringBeforeLastMark(String str,String mark)
    { 
        int l = str.lastIndexOf(mark);
        if(l == -1 || l == 0)
            return "";

        return str.substring(0, l);
    }
```